# Why do I receive usage info when trying to run bin/rails db:create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to use `bin/rails db:create` (or `bundle exec rails db:create`), I receive the usage info for `rails new`.

I'm using chruby with version 2.3.3 and Rails 5.0.0.1.

The goal here is just to create the databases....what's going on?

Comment: can't reproduce with MRI ruby 2.3.3 and rails 5.0.0.1

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - I'm not surprised. But I'm still getting it....

Comment: maybe your binstubs are out of date - what does `bin/rails -v` output?

Comment: @omnikron - I just created them a few minutes ago. Output is `Rails 5.0.0.1`

Comment: Ah, thought you might have just updated. I tried to look at the [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22288) where this was introduced but couldn't find anything, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this:

```
rake db:create
```

Comment: That does work. But I'd still like to know why the rails command didn't work.